# Python Dronekit Installation on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: dronekit-python

I'm having a bit of trouble installing python dronekit  on my raspberry pi 4B (8GB) (bullseye).

I know that dronekit does not support Python3, hence I am running a virtual python environement (dronekitty)

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screen shots (especially with very poor contrast) without at least posting the text.

Comment: In my experience, I was able to install with python3